# Using a cache manifest in a PhoneGap app

Tags: ios, html, cordova

I have a typical phone gap application with an `index.html` and assorted other `.js` and `.css` files in the `/www` folder.

Now, how should I go about updating these javascript/css files?  (Other than pushing a new app).  I thought I might use a cache manifest, but that requires them to be on the same domain so I don't think that will work...

The only thing I can come up with is source online copies of the scripts after the local ones, overriding all the function definitions in the local file, but that seems really lame.

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="http://online.com/script.js></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

put your code won googlecode.com , update your javascripts there , link your app  add the external host in your phonegap.plist to match *.googlecode.com and alter your code in there, it will automatically update the app with the new one